# LXC No space left on device when trying to delete instance

Tags: lxc, lxd

I tried to follow the the LXC tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-use-lxd-on-ubuntu-16-04

When running command `lxd init` I used all defaults except 1GB as disk space (my disk remaining free space is just 20GB so couldn't allocate more). I hope it would auto grow as in VirtualBox or Hyper-V.

Then I run `lxc launch ubuntu:20.04 webserver` but it show "not enough disk space". OK, so I want to try again with a bigger disk.

I run `lxc storage rm default`, it showed:

```
Error: The storage pool is currently in use
```

It makes sense I need to remove the VM first. I tried `lxc rm webserver` and it showed:

```
Error: Error deleting storage volume: Failed deleting subvolume "/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/webserver": Failed to run: btrfs subvolume delete /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/webserver: ERROR: cannot delete '/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/storage-pools/default/containers/webserver': No space left on device
```

I feel dumb because I want to reclaim disk space but it's like a dead loop. Google yields no result.

What should I do?
Thanks.

Additional information:
Host's host: Windows 10 Hyper-V, 20GB remaining, virtual size 1TB auto grow
Host: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: That looks like a btrfs error, but that tutorial does not use btrfs. Did you set that up yourself? How did you set up btrfs?

Comment: @MichaelHampton nope, the btrfs was preinstalled in the ubuntu 20.04, I installed the OS myself. I read that zfs is more stable but I want to try something preinstalled first.